# 64 bit division on linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm looking for a 64 bit division algorithm but not depends on GPL licence.

I found the following code in Hacker Delight book (Figure 9-5):

```
unsigned long long udivdi3(unsigned long long u,
unsigned long long v) 
if (v >> 32 == 0) {
    if (u >> 32 < v)
        return DIVU(u, v) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
else {
.....
     }
}
```

The problem is that 'return DIVU' calculate a division of 64/32 so it is no what I looking for.
What to do?

Comment: Can you use the pseudo-function `do_div()`?  That's what I use for 64-bit division in the kernel.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid GPL dependence in Linux Kernel code?

Comment: GPL dependence requires to make my project to open source. @ChrisStratton

Comment: Can you publish your code? @SteveSummit

Comment: @EliAvraham I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be tricky to do 64-bit division in Linux kernel code.  I'm not sure you're having the same problem I've had, but here's what I know.

It looks like the instruction sets don't fully handle 64-bit arithmetic.  It looks like gcc emits calls to helper functions.  For example, on ARM, if I write

```
t /= 86400;
```

where `t` is a 64-bit variable, my kernel build fails with "`undefined reference to '__aeabi_ldivmod'`".  Evidently the kernel doesn't link against the full C library where functions like `__aeabi_ldivmod` exist.

The solution seems to be to call `do_div` instead.  `do_div` isn't actually a function; it's a macro declared in an architecture-specific header file.  (For ARM, it's in `arch/arm/include/asm/div64.h`.  There's a similar file for x86.)

The solution is to replace `t /= 86400` with

```
(void)do_div(t, 86400);
```

`do_div` divides its first argument by its second, in-place, and returns the remainder (which I'm ignoring in this example).

There's a big comment in `div64.h` telling you more about `do_div` and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason that compiler-rt exists. [Here is the C implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/builtins/udivmoddi4.c) of what `__udivdi3` ultimately calls, but note that platform-specific assembly versions are also used, e.g. on x86.

But really, there's no point in avoiding libgcc for this - it is much more mature, supports many more platforms, and with the Runtime Library Exception the GPL is largely defanged - and you definitely shouldn't be modifying the upstream source for this so there's no modified source code that you have to make available.